# Drag and drop not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, drag-and-drop

Iam trying to use drag and drop. In an anchor tag I write my onsdragstart event as written down

```
<a href="xyz.action" ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('text/uri-list', 'abc.action?id=2')">drag</a>
```

Im trying to drop the item in a div

```
<div id="ccc" ondragover="event.preventDefault()" ondrop="doDrop1(event)"></div>
```

My javascript is as below:

```
 function doDrop1(event)
        {

           document.getElementById("mylock").value=1; 
          var links = event.dataTransfer.getData("text/uri-list").split("\n");
           alert(links)
}
```

In chrome the alert is `'http://localhost:8084/test/xyz.action'`
In firefox i'm getting correct  alert as `'abc.action?id=2'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **'event.dataTransfer.setData()'** use the data format as **'text'** instead of **'text/uri-list'**